# How can I make WAR file to be built with read only privileage in gradle project?

Tags: build.gradle

I'm new to the gradle project and I have been looking to add security/protection to the WAR file from tampering.

With reference to the gradle site https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html, tried using "fileMode" property in "build.gradle" as below and this didn't went well as I expected.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
war {
    fileMode 0444
}
```

where 0444 is numeric notation of the read-only access

Answer (score 0):

I came to know about jarsigner in java to add signature to the archive file. See below

Jar signing is an valid option to authenticate the owner of the WAR on Java run-time environment. This will include signature file (.SF) and signature block file (.DSA) to META-INF directory.

For more details about jar signing, [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) to know how to sign a jar file which can also be used to sign other archive file(s)

Time stamping the jar file while signing is advisable hence the certificate validity extension can be avoided.

Once the web archive is signed, deploy the archive in the web server. The verification part will be taken care of by java if the application is driven by "-jar" command in the command line argument.